# get the list of solr cores and insert it into array in php

Tags: php, solr

How can I get the list of solr cores and insert it into array in php. I would like to create an array variable in php which store the list of solr cores.
I was able to get a list of my cores by hitting this URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores Below show the partial result of the return:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":74},
  "initFailures":{},
  "status":{
    "Test17Jan":{
      "name":"Test17Jan",
    !-- Details removed --,
    "Test8Feb":{
      "name":"Test8Feb",
    !-- Details removed --,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) the output and get the name property of the returned status keys, like so:

```
$solr = json_decode($json);

foreach ($solr->status as $core) {
    echo "Found core ". $core->name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You can see a working sample here: https://3v4l.org/VcBDV